# Strange Behavior....Python class bound method retaining keyword arguments after call

Tags: python

I have a simple data model class for a GUI. In this class I have a addPnt method that attaches a timestamp if one is not passed through a keyword argument "timeDict". I expected that the default value ({}) would be set to timeDict at the start of every call to addPnt. However, while debuging, timeDict retains the values from the initial call to addPnt?!?! See code below

```
class LastTSDict(dict):
    def __getitem__( self, name ):
        try:
            return super( LastTSDict, self ).__getitem__( name )
        except KeyError:
            self.__setitem__(name,timestamp.getTimestamp())
            return self.__getitem__( name )

class DataElementDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,maxLen):
        self.maxLen=maxLen
        self.lastTS=LastTSDict()
    def __getitem__( self, name ):
        try:
            return super( DataElementDict, self ).__getitem__( name )
        except KeyError:
            if name==0:
                self.__setitem__(name,defaultdict(partial(defaultdict,partial(deque, maxlen=self.maxLen))))
            else:
                self.__setitem__(name,defaultdict(partial(defaultdict,partial(deque, maxlen=self.maxLen/8))))
            return self.__getitem__( name )

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self,maxLen=8192,extPeriods=[5,60,300,900,3600,86400]):
        self.DATA=DataElementDict(maxLen)
        self.extPeriods=extPeriods

    def addPnt(self,key,value,timeDict={}):
        try:
            pdb.set_trace()
            if 'ts' not in timeDict.keys():
                timeDict['ts']=timestamp.getTimestamp()
            if 'tu' not in timeDict.keys():
                timeDict['tu']=timestamp.unixTime(timeDict['ts'])
            self.DATA[0][key]['v'].append(value)
            for keyt in timeDict.keys():
                self.DATA[0][key][keyt].append(timeDict[keyt])
```

whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of default arguments is only created once at the defintion time of the function.

```
def addPnt(self,key,value,timeDict={}):
```

This means that every call uses the same dictionary object. Not a new one for each call.

To fix this use:

```
def addPnt(self,key,value,timeDict=None):
    if timeDict is None:
        timeDict = {}
```