# Clearing a Python Class embedded list (actual issue: return closes function)

Tags: python, list, class

How can one use a function to clear an class embedded list? Here is code that reproduces the behavior.

```
class LogClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logList=[]
    def __call__(self,msg='',Data={},Level=1,Exc=False):
        self.logList.append((msg,Data,Level,Exc))
    def read(self):
        return self.logList
        self.logList[:]=[]
```

the function read should clear the list after being called. However, self.logList contents persist. I assume it has something to do with copying the contents in the return line above, but I am unsure how to rectify the problem.

Code in use:

```
class LogClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logList=[]
    def __call__(self,msg='',Data=None,Level=1,Exc=False,Verbose=''):
        if not Data:
            Data={}
        self.logList.append((msg,Data,Level,Exc,TimeStamp(),Verbose))
    def read(self):
        L=self.logList
        self.logList=[]
        return L
```

while i think i have addressed the Data={} mutable default argument, I was unable to recreate the spurious effects featured in the link you posted. For instance keeping Data={} in the **call** argument and running the following:

```
In [109]: Log("1st call",Data={"call":1}) 

In [110]: Log("2nd call")

In [111]: Log("3rd call",Data={"call":3})

In [112]: Log.read()
Out[112]: 
[('1st call', {'call': 1}, 1, False, 1506568154.223882, ''),
 ('2nd call', {}, 1, False, 1506568167.787137, ''),
 ('3rd call', {'call': 3}, 1, False, 1506568176.463921, '')]
```

I should be more vigilant though, as I have fallen prey [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371334/strange-behavior-python-class-bound-method-retaining-keyword-arguments-after).

Comment: @PRMoureu Well we probably wants to return the current value of `self.logList` first, so he'll need to save it in a temporary variable.

Comment: Also, watch out for that [mutable default argument](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Comment: see edit above about mutable default argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` ends execution of the method, so nothing below it will be run. You want something like:

```
def read(self):
    old_list = self.logList
    self.logList = []
    return old_list
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` ends execution and `self.logList[:]=[]` is unreachable. If you want return value of `self.logList` and clear this variable you can use that code:

```
def read(self):
    old_log_list = self.logList.copy()  # copy of field for return old value
    self.logList[:]=[]
    return old_log_list
```

EDIT:

@Peter DeGlopper version is better. I suggested @scientificCompNoob code and I needlessly  create a copy of the field, but it is necessary when you use `self.logList [:] = []` instead of`self.logList = []`